# Static Method in Parent Class Refers to Child Class

Tags: class, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have these two subclasses (psuedo code):

Male.class:

```
include Person.class;

class Male extends Person {
    ...
}
```

Female.class:

```
include Person.class;

class Female extends Person {
    ...
}
```

And finally I have this base class:

Person.class:

```
class Person {

    static function makePersonBySettings(settings) {
        var person;

        if(settings.gender == 'male') {
            person = new Male(settings.name);
        }
        else if(settings.gender == 'female') {
            person = new Female(settings.name);
        }

        return person;
    }

}
```

Parent's static method depends on knowing what Male.class and Female.class are. I can't do importing of subclasses (e.g., `import Male.class`) at the top of Parent.class because the subclass depends on knowing the parent.

What's the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You could decouple the factory method (makePersonBySettings) from your parent class by creating a dedicated class to contain factory methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person {

    static function makePersonBySettings(settings) {

        var person;

        person = new self(settings.name);

        return person;
    }

}
```

`self` will reference your child object.

`Male::makePersonBySettings(settings)` will return a `Male` object.